# Android - readLine(); crashes my application

Tags: java, android, arduino

I have set a server at an [Arduino Leonardo](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardLeonardo) using an Ethernet [shield](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoShields). Through a socket connection, I can send strings from my Android application to my Arduino that I can succesfully read. A part of my Arduino code is:

```
if (client.available() > 0) {
    char thisChar = client.read();
    if (readString.length() < 30){
        readString.concat(thisChar);
    }
    if (thisChar == '\n') {
        if (readString.indexOf("connect") > 0) {
            client.print("connection_ok");
        }
        if (readString.indexOf("change") >= 0) {
            changeLedState();   // Set the LED on
        }
    }
}
```

While my Android code is:

```
Socket s = new Socket("192.168.0.177",23);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
if (s.isConnected()){
     out.println("connect\n");
     BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
     String line = r.readLine();
}
```

My Android application always crashes at `readLine();`. If I use `out.print ("change");`, changeLedState really happens, so I know I can read output strings from my Android application, but I have not managed to read the input strings from Arduino to Android.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Presumably you *actually* have an exception at `readLine`? If so, why not give us that information?

Comment: Define 'crash'. NB there is zero probability that isConnected() will return false at that point in the code.

Comment: can you explain me about exceptions? i have realised that my app crashes when it gets no input.. if i send from arduino the answer "connection_ok" after a 2 sec delay it works just fine, so i reached the conclusion that sometimes the answer is so fast that my app misses it and it is still waiting for an answer that never comes. am i right? i have used try and catch but withoun doing anything in catches..

Comment: to be more clear when my app gets no input in general readLine crashes, so i think i can handle that with ioexceptions, i just don't know how, thanks a lot guys for the support..

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `indexOf("connect") > 0` to `indexOf("connect") >= 0`.

Or better, use something like `startsWith` (which returns a boolean) instead of `indexOf` if that's what you really mean.